# How to update an object with data from another object nested in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So i need to write a function which updates my object with another object (but this object is inside an array) , for example:

```
  const mazda = { model: 5, seria: 22, wheels: 4,};
```

and i want to add data from :

```
const newItems= [{ LCDscreen: true },{ wheels: 5 },{ model: 6},{ weight: 500},{ mirrors: 4},];
```

but so the seria from 1st object is unchanged. The result should be

```
{ seria: 22 ,model: 6, wheels: 4, LCDscreen: true, weight: 500 , mirrors: 4};
```

Whats the best approach?

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to be?

Comment: do you want to change the existing values or append onto it?

Comment: const mazda = { seria: 22 ,model: 6, wheels: 4, LCDscreen: true, weight: 500 ,  mirrors: 4};

Comment: I Want to add values from second object to the first one, without changing seria.

Comment: Why  `wheels: 4` is not updated with `5` in the output?

Comment: @ViktorRusse , but the 2nd one is an array  , not object ❌. Or is it, i'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a single line:

```js
newItems.reduce((acc, patch) => Object.assign(acc, patch), mazda)
```

This iterates over all objects in the `newItems` list and merges them into `mazda` one after one.

If you don't want the `mazda` object to be modified but instead get a new object, use an empty object (`{}`) as first parameter to `Object.assign`:

```js
const newMazda = newItems.reduce((acc, patch) => Object.assign({}, acc, patch), mazda)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple loop through the array and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array objects inside the mazda object. This is the fastest method after using a for loop.

```js
let mazda = { model: 5, seria: 22, wheels: 4,};

const newItems= [{ LCDscreen: true },{ wheels: 5 },{ model: 6},{ weight: 500},{ mirrors: 4}]

newItems.forEach(item => {
      mazda = {...mazda, ...item};
});

console.log(mazda)
```

Comment: You are using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), not [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Sorry my bad. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this does what you want it to. Take each item in the `newList` and add it as a new property to the `mazda` object.

```js
const mazda = { model: 5, seria: 22, wheels: 4,};

const newItems= [{ LCDscreen: true },{ wheels: 5 },{ model: 6},{ weight: 500},{ mirrors: 4}]

const result = newItems.reduce( (acc,item) => ({...acc,...item}),mazda);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can you explaint what is the use of `...`  ?

Comment: @SandrinJoy Yes sure it is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)